# importing my own python modules

Tags: python

I have written a small python module called phpcs. I
folder structure
    cs_qa_support
        phpcs 
            **init**.py
            config_file.py
        setup.py

contents of setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='cs_qa_support',
      version='0.1',
      description='QA Support',
      packages=['phpcs'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

I installed this using the command

```
pip install -e .
```

the file phpcs/**init**.py is empty
the content of phpcs/confif_file is

```
class PhpcsConfigFile:
    def __init__(self,configFileName):
        self.__config_file_name = configFileName
    def dump(self):
        print self.__config_file_name
```

given all of that I want to start using the module

my first attempt

```
>>> import phpcs
>>> config_file.PhpcsConfigFile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'config_file' is not defined
```

second attempt

```
>>> from phpcs import config_file
>>> config_file.PhpcsConfigFile
<class phpcs.config_file.PhpcsConfigFile at 0x7fe5ef4b7738>
```

My question is can I avoid typing config_file.PhpcsConfigFile and just use PhpcsConfigFile?

Thanks

Comment: `from phpcs.config_file import PhpcsConfigFile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this
**from phpcs import config file as con**
then do this
**con.phpcsConfifFile**